# ASP.NET Dynamic Stylesheet

Tags: asp.net, stylesheet

I would like to  apply stylesheet class for controls based on some conditions. Say

```
If (RepeatedUser)
{
    applyThisStyleSheetClass
}

else
{
   applyAnotherStyleSheetClass
}
```

Do i need to create any custom control /Custom Property / Extension method to achieve this?

Comment: One way si to use jQuery on document.ready  check for if repeater is used then change class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try an extension method

```
 public static void ApplyCss(this WebControl control, string cssClass)
 {
        control.CssClass += " " + cssClass;
 }
```

You can use it in your code

```
If (RepeatedUser)
{
   Label1.ApplyCss("GreenClass");
}

else
{
   Label1.ApplyCss("BlueClass");
}
```